# ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.3.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 return SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: linux, ifconfig

I'm setting an alias IP on eth0 by using 'ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.3.1 netmask 255.255.255.0'. But there's an error popup:
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot assign requested address
SIOCSIFNETMASK: Cannot assign requested address

The version of ifconfig is:
net-tools 1.60
ifconfig 1.42 (2001-04-13)

The error is caused by the ioctl() function inside ifconfig source code:
/* Set a certain interface flag. */
static int set_flag(char *ifname, short flag)
{
    struct ifreq ifr;

```
safe_strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, ifname, IFNAMSIZ);
if (ioctl(skfd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr) < 0) {
fprintf(stderr, _("%s: unknown interface: %s\n"), 
    ifname, strerror(errno));
return (-1);
}
safe_strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, ifname, IFNAMSIZ);
ifr.ifr_flags |= flag;
**if (ioctl(skfd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr) < 0) {
perror("SIOCSIFFLAGS");
return -1;
}**
return (0);
```

}

My question is, could anyone help explain why ioctl(skfd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr) returns Cannot assign requested address     (errno=99)

Answer (score 0):

Though no one has answered this question, I think I'm reaching the root cause.

The devinet.c in net\ipv4 give me some informations.